# FullText search by FullName when FullName is not a column, but has firstName and LastName

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a below query, i do not have a fullName field , but queryText input can have fullname.
my search by firstName or lastName works, but user provides both first and last name it does not work.

```
@queryText of 
John Works
Doe  Works
John Doe  Does not work

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [HK].[User]
 (   
  UserName,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  NickName,
  EmailAddress,
  WorkPhone  
 )   
  KEY INDEX [PK_HK.User]
      ON [HKUserCatalog]
      WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO ,
      STOPLIST = SYSTEM
      ;   
GO 

my sql

    SELECT TOP(@queryLimit) * FROM [User]
            WHERE
                CONTAINS((UserName, FirstName, LastName, NickName, EmailAddress, WorkPhone), @queryText)
                OR TRY_CONVERT(INT, @queryText) = UserId
                Order By FirstName, LastName
                ;
```

**How do i make it work without adding a fullName column to the table? i tried using http://www.22bugs.co/post/searching-peoples-names-with-sql-server-full-text-search/ but does not work either**

Answer (score 1):

I see you don't want to add the `FullName` column to your table but in case you change your mind and If you are allowed to modify your `[HK].User` table then here is how you can add a computed column called `FullName` and include it in your full text index:

```
alter table [HK].[User] add [FullName] as (isnull(FirstName,'') + ' ' + isnull(LastName,''))

alter fulltext index on [HK].[User] disable
alter fulltext index on [HK].[User] add (FullName)
alter fulltext index on [HK].[User] enable
```

Then include this column in your `CONTAINS` predicate:

```
SELECT TOP(@queryLimit) * FROM [User]
       WHERE
           CONTAINS((UserName, FullName, NickName, EmailAddress, WorkPhone), @queryText)
           OR TRY_CONVERT(INT, @queryText) = UserId
       Order By FirstName, LastName
       ;
```

This way when `FirstName` or `LastName` columns values change the full text index for `FullName` will be auto updated and all your provided sample queries should return desired result.

Note, if you want you can even include `Nickname` column into `FullName` definition and it will make your `CONTAINS` condition even smaller and easier to read.

I personally think a computed FTS-indexed column is the best for this kind of task unless you have restrictions which may prevent you from adding it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The example which you provided has only one `Name` column, it is not same with your case. When you want to search `"John Doe"`, the Full Text Search fetchs the condition for per column. So, you should create multiple `Contains` by using `AND`;

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE
CONTAINS(FirstName, '"John"') and CONTAINS(LastName, '"Doe"');
```

Comment: but my query could be just John or Doe or John Doe

Comment: You can't perform it by using this design. You should create just "Name" column then.